# Узнать номер символа, который нужно удалить чтобы строка стала палиндромом

Tags: c++, if, for, олимпиада

Накопал в интернете разные коды на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string>

std::string palindrome(const std::string& s) {
    if (s.size() == 0 || s.size() == 1) {
        return s;
    }
    if (s.front() == s.back()) {
        return s.front() + palindrome(s.substr(1, s.size() - 2)) + s.back();
    }
    std::array<std::string, 3> branches; 
    branches[0] = palindrome(s.substr(1));
    branches[1] = palindrome(s.substr(0, s.size() - 1));
    branches[2] = palindrome(s.substr(1, s.size() - 2));

    return *std::max_element(branches.begin(), branches.end(), []
        (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
            return a.size() < b.size();
        });
}

int main()
{
    std::string target{ "12343271" };
    std::cout << palindrome(target) << std::endl;
}
```

Программа работает, но выводит палиндром - готовый, а должно быть число...
Подскажите как исправить программу

Comment: я бы не рекомендовал пользоваться этим кодом. Лучше написать нормально. 1 - этот код пытается найти максимальный палиндром. 2 - сложность около экспоненциальной. 3 - если вы понимаете что тут написано (я не думаю) то место замены найти не сложно.

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста исправить этот код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не ожидал что задача вызовет сложности. Решение за линейно.

```
bool ok(const char* l, const char* r){
    while (l < r){
        if (*l != *r)
            return false;
        l++;
        r--;
    }
    return true;
}

int getPosition(const char *inp){
    const char* l = inp;
    const char* r = inp;
    while (*r) r++;
    r--;
    while (l < r){
        if (*l == *r)l++,r--;
        else if (ok(l+1,r))
            return l-inp+1;
        else if (ok(l,r-1))
            return r-inp+1;
        else return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Запускаемый пример https://ideone.com/ngfBi6

Answer (score 1):

Обращаю внимание на то, что задача взята из школьного этапа всероссийской олимпиады школьников по информатике, которая идёт сейчас, поэтому помогать автору вопроса в несамостоятельном выполнении соревновательного задания не есть здорово.

*С уважением, председатель региональной предметно-методической комиссии всероссийской олимпиады школьников по информатике в г. Москве*

Comment: да не он один. Понимаем мы всё прекрасно, но всё равно начали отвечать... Руками проверять будете решения?

Comment: Вопрос такой возник. Что планируется делать с текущей олимпиадой, и не дискредитирована ли сама концепция заочных олимпиад продолжительностью больше скажем часов 5? Если захотите в личку ответить, то ссылка на вк в профиле

Comment: Не знаю кто так решил пошутить(каждый может себя выдать за кого угодно), но если считать, что   в  Москве  проводится такая олимпиада, то  Председатель региональной предметно-методической комиссии всероссийской олимпиады школьников должен в первую очередь  подумать о плохой организации олимпиады, и есть ли здорово то, как он сам выполняет свою работу?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan самое печальное, что это реально олимпиада в Москве. Но это заочный этап. Организатор особо ничего сделать не может. Да и по факту такие ученики только своей школе нагадят.